# css can't change the space between the input text fields

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use this contact form script http://plugins.theodin.co.uk/jquery/contactable.1.3/index.html which is great however I have one problem, as I add 1 or 2 fields, the space between the fields is greater and looks bad. How can I remove the space between the input text fields?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add some code/an image (or preferably) a http://jsfiddle.net showing the problem.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  And as Rory is asking, please post an actual example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding new fields in their own paragraph tags.

For example, to add a new field, I would insert this above or below another field.

```
<p>
  <label for="new_field">New Field <span class="red"> * </span></label>
  <br>
  <input name="new_field" class="contact" id="new_field">
</p>
```

The final code would something like:

```
<form action="" method="" id="contactForm" style="margin-left: -10px;">
  <div class="holder">
    <p>
      <label for="new_field">New Field <span class="red"> * </span></label>
      <br>
      <input name="new_field" class="contact" id="new_field">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name<span class="red"> * </span></label>
      <br>
      <input name="name" class="contact" id="name">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">Email <span class="red"> * </span></label>
      <br>
      <input id="email" class="contact" name="email">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="message">Message <span class="red"> * </span></label>
      <br>
      <textarea cols="30" rows="4" class="message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="submit">
    </p>
    <p class="disclaimer">Please feel free to get in touch, we value your feedback</p>
  </div>
</form>
```